# Update Spreadsheet when new Docs are added to a Folder Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

For my job I need to list al Jpegs with name and Url into a spreadsheet. These Jpegs are put into a folder on the Drive. My script works and whenever I update it, it will clear the sheet and write all the info I need on the Spreadsheet. However, It doesn't update the spreadsheet automatically when I put in new Jpegs in the folder. Although it does not have to be automatic, I would love to only update the new jpegs instead of clearing everything and let the script write everything again. this is due some folders contain up to 3000 images, which takes ages to load and sometimes gives me the runtime error.

I tried multiple codes to just update and add new rows whenever a new entity is detected in that folder, nothing works. I know how it is possible to update from a spreadsheet but not from a folder and can't seem to figure it out. Please see the code below. It would be really appreciated to give me an answer or a heads up how to find an answer.

```
         function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "CLICK TO UPDATE List", functionName: "Updatelist"}];
  ss.addMenu("Click to update list", menuEntries);
} 
function Updatelist() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('My-Folder-ID-HE');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date;

sheet.clear();

  var headers = [["Name", "link", "Total jpegs in folder"]];
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);
  sheet.getRange("C2").setFormula("=COUNTA(A2:A)");

while(contents.hasNext()) {
   file = contents.next();
   name = file.getName();
   link = file.getUrl();
   data = [name, link]
   sheet.appendRow(data);


 }
} 


function initializeTrigger(){ 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('My-Folder-ID');
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}
function myFunction(e){
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
    // do Something
  Browser.msgBox('New row(s) added');
 }
};
```

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `appendRow` in a loop which is very time consuming...

Use an array and write this array to your sheet in one single call to make your script more efficient.

### relevant part of the code to replace :

```
function Updatelist() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B#####################5UUU');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date;

  sheet.clear();

  var headers = [["Name", "link", "Total jpegs in folder"]];
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);
  sheet.getRange("C2").setFormula("=COUNTA(A2:A)");

  var sheetContent=[];
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    data = [name, link]
    sheetContent.push(data)
  }
  sheet.getRange(3,1,sheetContent.length,sheetContent[0].length).setValues(sheetContent);// adapt the starting row/column value to your needs
}
```

**Note :**

Updating the sheet when a new doc is added would need to periodically read the folder's content and compare it to the sheet's data which would be even more complicated and time consuming than simply clear the sheet and update its content. On the other hand, there is no event related to "adding a doc to a folder" so the only possibility it to check on a time basis. That's why I simply suggest a faster and more efficient way to get data. I would create a trigger to run it every hour, assuming there is no emergency in that matter ;-) –

Comment: Hi Serge, Thanks. However, Does the sheet update automatically now whenever I put in a new doc in the folder or does it have to clear the sheet again?

Comment: Updating the sheet when a new doc is added would need to periodically read the folder's content and compare it to the sheet's data which would be even more complicated and time consuming than simply clear the sheet and update its content. On the other hand, there is no event related to "adding a doc to a folder" so the only possibility it to check on a time basis. That's why I simply suggest a faster and more efficient way to get data. I would create a trigger to run it every hour, assuming there is no emergency in that matter ;-)